# zf2 create select/drop down box and populate options in controller?

Tags: zend-framework2

To Create a text input box I used folling code in zend framework2

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class Loginform extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
           $this->add(array(            
            'name' => 'usernames',
            'attributes' =>  array(
                'id' => 'usernames',                
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'User Name',
            ),
        ));       
    }
}
```

and I can populate the values in controller action using

```
$form = new Loginform();
$form->get('usernames')->setAttribute('value', 'user 1');
```

Any idea how can I do the same for Selection/drop down box in zf2?

Ref: [zend framework 2 documentation](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the API (the docs are terrible, so check the code).

Use the `Zend\Form\Element\Select` class and set the options attribute like so:

```
$element->setAttribute('options', array(
    'key' => 'val',
    ...
));
```

Output the element using the `FormRow` or `FormSelect` view helper.

This site is also a good source for examples and information: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Example:

```
$this->add(array(     
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
    'name' => 'usernames',
    'attributes' =>  array(
        'id' => 'usernames',                
        'options' => array(
            'test' => 'Hi, Im a test!',
            'Foo' => 'Bar',
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'User Name',
    ),
));
```

You can also assign the options in the controller if you need to, as shown above.

Comment: can you provide me complete example selection box or rechange my above code

Comment: the confusion is terrible between elementOptions and elementOptions (values)

Answer (score 4):

```
$form = new Loginform();      
$form->get('usernames')->setValueOptions($usernames );
```

***$usernames*** is an array

Ref [Click Here](https://unofficial-zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.element.select.html?highlight=test)

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework 2.2 , select options have been moved into 'options' instead of 'attributes' so above code will be changed too

```
$this->add(array(     
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
    'name' => 'usernames',
    'attributes' =>  array(
       'id' => 'usernames'              
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'User Name',
        'options' => array(
            'test' => 'Hi, Im a test!',
            'Foo' => 'Bar',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in controller then do it like this way

```
$form->get('ELEMENT_NAME')->setAttribute('options' ,array('KEY' => 'VALUE'));
```