# create drop-down list zendframework 2

Tags: drop-down-menu, zend-form, zend-framework2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a drop down list in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460840/create-a-drop-down-list-in-zend-framework-2)

I getting started with zf2..

I was wondering how to create a drop-down list within the Form getting the options from a database??

this might be a newbie question, but I'm having a hard time doing it..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

Create a class that extends Fieldset.

Implement the class InputFilterProviderInterface if you want some sort of validation for this field.

To access the service manager, it needs to Implement the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and two methods, setServiceLocator () and getServiceLocator ().

By default, the Zend Framework MVC registers an initializer that will inject the ServiceManager instance into any class implementing Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface. [read this](http://zend-framework-2-doc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service.manager.quick.start.html)

```php
namespace Users\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class GroupsFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface, 
        ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct('groups');

        $this->setLabel('Group');

        $this->setName('groups');

        $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $sm = $sl->get('Users\Model\GroupsTable');

        $groups = $sm->fetchAll();

        $select = new Element\Select('groups');

        $options = array();

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $options[$group->id] = $group->name;
        }

        $select->setValueOptions($options);
    }

    /**
     * Set serviceManager instance
     *
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve serviceManager instance
     *
     * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return multitype:multitype:boolean
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification ()
    {
        return array(
                'name' => array(
                        'required' => true
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Than in module.php

```php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'Users\Model\UsersTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter1 = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $table1     = new UsersTable($dbAdapter1);
                        return $table1;
                    }, // Adapter and table groups here
                    'Users\Model\GroupsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter2 = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $table2     = new GroupsTable($dbAdapter2);
                        return $table2;
                    },
            ),
    );
}
```

and finally in your Form

```php
    $groups = new GroupsFieldset();
    $this->add($groups);
```

Comment: How are you getting the service manager in there?

Comment: Im getting Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in $sm = $sl->get('Dashboard\Model\DepTable');. DepTable is working fine, I can list, add, delete, etc

Comment: I'm guessing it is because the Service Locator is not set. The ServiceLocatorAware interface will cause the ServiceLocator to be injected into the object but this would occur after the class has been instantiated. A good blog post on this issue - http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=205